# A Simple Question about Poles

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

If $f$ be a meromorphic function on the complex plane and $(1-|z|)|f(z)|$ $\longrightarrow$ $0$ as $|z|$ $\longrightarrow$ 1 then show that $f$ does not have any pole on the unit circle.
This looks very simple but I somehow have not able to prove it rigorously. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think we can proceed through contradiction, like suppose $f$ has a pole on $|z| =1$ then t must be of the form $f(z) = \frac{\phi(z)}{|z|-1}$ ?.where $\phi(z) \neq 0$ on $|z| = 1$

Comment: How are you getting this expression? I know f(z)=g(z)/(z-z_0)^n if f has a pole of order n at z_0?

Comment: Just thought that it must blow up at the pole,well I might be wrong then?

Comment: Hint: Suppose $|z_0| = 1.$ Then for $0<r<1,$ $|rz_0 - z_0| = 1-|rz_0|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume a pole at $z=1$ so that $f(z)=\dfrac{g(z)}{(1-z)^n}$ with $g(1)$ finite and nonzero.

Then

$$\lim_{z\to1}(1-|z|)\left|\frac{g(z)}{(1-z)^n}\right|=g(1)\lim_{z\to1}\left|\frac{1-|z|}{(1-z)^n}\right|\ne 0.$$

For example,

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left|\frac{1-|1+\epsilon|}{\epsilon^n}\right|\ne 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $|z_0|=1$ and $z\in \{rz_0: 0\le r \le1\},$ then $|z-z_0| = 1-|z|.$